# String length always 0

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

I am trying to teach myself C,so I am writing a program to see if a string is present at the end of another string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int containsAtEnd(char *s,  char *t);
int strlen(char *s);

int main()
{
    char *x = "tacocat";
    char *y = "bol";
    printf("%d\n", strend(x, y));
    getchar();
    return 0;
}


int strlen(char *s)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i != '\0'; ++i)
        ;
    printf("%d", i);
    return i;
}

int containsAtEnd(char *s, char *t)
{
    int tlen = strlen(*t);
    int slen = strlen(*s);
    int i = 0;
    s += slen - tlen;
    while ((*s == *t) && *s != '\0')
        i++; s++; t++;
    if (i < (tlen-1))
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Yet,  regardless of the strings given in the main function, "001" is always printed, indicating that the length of both the strings in 0 and the second string is present in the first.

Comment: `i != '\0'` --> `s[i] != '\0'`, `int tlen = strlen(*t);` --> `int tlen = strlen(t);`

Comment: read warning of the compiler !

Comment: `while(...)` --> `while(...){ ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try if the following code can help you. I would also advice you to use an IDE or an analysis program that tells you about taking pointer from integer without a cast and conditions that are always true (or always false).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int containsAtEnd(char *s,  char *t);
int strlen(char *s);

int strlen(char *s)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        ;
    printf("%d", i);
    return i;
}

int containsAtEnd(char *s, char *t)
{
    int tlen = strlen(t);
    int slen = strlen(s);
    int i = 0;
    s += slen - tlen;
    while ((*s == *t) && *s != '\0') {
        i++; s++; t++;
    }
    if (i < (tlen-1))
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

int main()
{
    char *x = "tacocat";
    char *y = "bol";
    printf("%d\n", containsAtEnd(x, y));

    char *x2 = "foobarbaz";
    char *y2 = "bar";
    printf("%d\n", containsAtEnd(x2, y2));

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```